# Проблема с Rest оператором js

Tags: javascript

функция возвращает массив с теми аргументами, которые соответствуют типу данных, переданному в первом аргументе но если я возвращаю  не `console.log( arr )` а просто `arr` то выводится undefined почему?

```
function filterByType(type, ...theArgs){
  let arr = theArgs.filter(function(e){
   return  typeof(e) == type;
  });
  return console.log( arr );
}  
filterByType('number',12, 'merge' ,434 ,23);// возвращает [12,434,23]
```

Answer (score 1):

всё нормально работает

```js
function filterByType(type, ...theArgs){
  let arr = theArgs.filter(function(e){
   return  typeof(e) == type;
  });
  return arr;
}  
console.log(filterByType('number',12, 'merge' ,434 ,23));
```